# Django test login fails unless a completely un-related, totally trivial function is either commented out or renamed

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm getting a strange error in my Django testing code.

Full code:

```
from .models                    import MIN_BIRTH_YEAR
from .models                    import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test                import TestCase
import factory

TEST_USERS = []
TEST_PASSWORD = 'password123abc'

class UserProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
    birth_year = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n + MIN_BIRTH_YEAR - 1)

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
    profile = factory.RelatedFactory(UserProfileFactory, 'user')

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_username{}'.format(n))
    first_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_first_name{}'.format(n))
    last_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_last_name{}'.format(n))
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_email{}@example.com'.format(n))
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password', TEST_PASSWORD)

def create_insert_test_users():
    for i in range(5):
        TEST_USERS.append(UserFactory.create())

def _test_one_logged_in_user(test_instance, test_user_index):
    """
    In addition to public information, private content for a single
    logged-in user should be somewhere on the page.
    """
    test_instance.client.logout()

    test_user = TEST_USERS[test_user_index]

    print('Attempting to login:')
    profile = test_user.profile
    print('test_user.id=' + str(test_user.id))
    print('   username=' + test_user.username + ', password=' + TEST_PASSWORD)
    print('   first_name=' + test_user.first_name + ', last_name=' + test_user.last_name)
    print('   email=' + test_user.email)
    print('   profile=' + str(profile))
    print('      profile.birth_year=' + str(profile.birth_year))
```

Continued. This is the login line I'm talking about. This `_test_one_logged_in_user` function is called by the second to last line (`_test_one_logged_in_user(self, 0)`) below:

```
    did_login_succeed = test_instance.client.login(
        username=test_user.username,
        password=TEST_PASSWORD)
    test_instance.assertTrue(did_login_succeed)

    ##########################################
    # GET PAGE AND TEST ITS CONTENTS HERE...
    ##########################################

class MainPageTestCase(TestCase):
    """Tests for the main page."""
    def setUp(self_ignored):
        """Insert test users."""
        create_insert_test_users()

    def test_true_is_true(self):
        """Public information should be somewhere on the page."""
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_logged_in_users(self):
        """
        In addition to public information, private content for logged in
        users should also be somewhere on the page.
        """
        _test_one_logged_in_user(self, 0)
        _test_one_logged_in_user(self, 1)
```

This works fine. Everything passes. But change the name of `test_true_is_true` to `test_content_not_logged_in`

```
def test_content_not_logged_in(self):
    """Public information should be somewhere on the page."""
    self.assertTrue(True)
```

and `test_instance.client.login` now returns `False`...which results in the assertion below it

```
test_instance.assertTrue(did_login_succeed)
```

to fail: `AssertionError: False is not true`. If you comment out the entire function, though, it succeeds (login returns `True`).

```
# def test_content_not_logged_in(self):
#     """Public information should be somewhere on the page."""
#     self.assertTrue(True)
```

If you uncomment it and rename it to any of the following, it works:

- `test_xcontent_not_logged_in`
- `test__content_not_logged_in`
- `test_not_logged_in`

Any of these, and it fails:

- `test_ctrue_is_true`
- `test_cxontent_not_logged_in`
- `test_contentnot_logged_in`
- `test_contennot_logged_in`
- `test_contenot_logged_in`
- `test_contnot_logged_in`
- `test_connot_logged_in`
- `test_cnot_logged_in`
- `test_c`

(I've [searched for `test_c`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#qscrl=1&q=%22test_c%22+python) and found *something* but nothing that indicates anything particularly special.)

This seems to imply that the `setUp` function runs once for `test_content_not_logged_in` (the trivial function), and then again for `test_logged_in_users`. And this running twice is causing problems. So I changed it so the users are only created if the `TEST_USER` array is empty:

```
def create_insert_test_users():
    if  len(TEST_USERS) == 0:
        for i in range(5):
            TEST_USERS.append(UserFactory.create())
```

But it's still failing, and I can confirm it's failing with the user having an id of 1:

```
$ python -Wall manage.py test auth_lifecycle.test__view_main2
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle_venv/lib/python3.4/site.py:165: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
  f = open(fullname, "rU")
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle_venv/lib/python3.4/imp.py:32: PendingDeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  PendingDeprecationWarning)
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.Attempting to login:
test_user.id=1
   username=test_username1, password=password123abc
   first_name=test_first_name1, last_name=test_last_name1
   email=test_email1@example.com
   profile=test_username1
      profile.birth_year=1887
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_logged_in_users (auth_lifecycle.test__view_main2.MainPageTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/auth_lifecycle/test__view_main2.py", line 74, in test_logged_in_users
    _test_one_logged_in_user(self, 0)
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/auth_lifecycle/test__view_main2.py", line 53, in _test_one_logged_in_user
    test_instance.assertTrue(did_login_succeed)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.385s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

---

models.py:

```
"""Defines a single extra user-profile field for the user-authentication
    lifecycle demo project:

    - Birth year, which must be between <link to MIN_BIRTH_YEAR> and
    <link to MAX_BIRTH_YEAR>, inclusive.
"""
from datetime                   import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions     import ValidationError
from django.db                  import models

OLDEST_EVER_AGE     = 127  #:Equal to `127`
YOUNGEST_ALLOWED_IN_SYSTEM_AGE = 13   #:Equal to `13`
MAX_BIRTH_YEAR      = datetime.now().year - YOUNGEST_ALLOWED_IN_SYSTEM_AGE
"""Most recent allowed birth year for (youngest) users."""
MIN_BIRTH_YEAR      = datetime.now().year - OLDEST_EVER_AGE
"""Most distant allowed birth year for (oldest) users."""

def _validate_birth_year(birth_year_str):
    """Validator for <link to UserProfile.birth_year>, ensuring the
        selected year is between <link to OLDEST_EVER_AGE> and
        <link to MAX_BIRTH_YEAR>, inclusive.
        Raises:
            ValidationError: When the selected year is invalid.

        https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/validators/

        I am a recovered Hungarian Notation junkie (I come from Java). I
        stopped using it long before I started with Python. In this
        particular function, however, because of the necessary cast, it's
        appropriate.
    """
    birth_year_int = -1
    try:
        birth_year_int = int(str(birth_year_str).strip())
    except TypeError:
        raise ValidationError(u'"{0}" is not an integer'.format(birth_year_str))

    if  not (MIN_BIRTH_YEAR <= birth_year_int <= MAX_BIRTH_YEAR):
        message = (u'{0} is an invalid birth year.'
                   u'Must be between {1} and {2}, inclusive')
        raise ValidationError(message.format(
            birth_year_str, MIN_BIRTH_YEAR, MAX_BIRTH_YEAR))
    #It's all good.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """Extra information about a user: Birth year.

        ---NOTES---

        Useful related SQL:
            - `select id from auth_user where username <> 'admin';`
            - `select * from auth_lifecycle_userprofile where user_id=(x,x,...);`
    """
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    birth_year = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Year you were born",
        validators=[_validate_birth_year])

    # Override the __str__() method to return out something meaningful
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the name of the test, you change the order in which the tests run. The test_logged_in_users method runs BEFORE test_true_is_true but runs AFTER test_c_whatever (presumably because it's running them in alpha or some sort of order). This is why you're seeing the weirdness with the name changes.

As you figured out, your setUp method runs for each test case.  When your setUp runs the first time, Users are created and saved to both the DB and TEST_USERS. When your second test runs, your DB is refreshed, and all your users are deleted. The users represented by TEST_USERS (which are still in your list, because your globals persist across test cases) no longer exist in the DB.

You can make your test pass in your original code by resetting TEST_USERS, like this:

```
def create_insert_test_users():
    # global tells python to use the TEST_USERS above, not create a new one
    global TEST_USERS
    TEST_USERS = []
    # Your code here...
```

Now, TEST_USERS represents new, real users that match users in the DB. Generally speaking, though, globals are a bad idea ([for several reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), the confusion you're experiencing being among them). Creating them on-the-fly (as you're working toward in your latest update) is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) will recognize all the tests by looking for methods that start with `test`

From documentation:

> The individual tests are defined with methods whose names start
>   with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner
>   about which methods represent tests.

So when you rename `a_trivial_function` it changes whether it is considered a test or not.

Comment: Oops. Of course. I'm updating the question. The problem is still happening with `test...`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The original code stores `TEST_USERS` locally, and it seems that statically-held object was causing problems when shared among the tests. I naively thought it was important to store the objects locally, in order to compare the database values against it. That implies I don't trust Django or Factory Boy to correctly insert them into the database, and they can handle that just fine.

Here's the updated code, which only stores the objects in the database. I also moved the contents sub-function containing `login` directly into the bottom function.

```
from .models                    import MIN_BIRTH_YEAR
from .models                    import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test                import TestCase
import factory

TEST_PASSWORD = 'password123abc'
TEST_USER_COUNT = 5

class UserProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
    birth_year = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n + MIN_BIRTH_YEAR - 1)

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
    profile = factory.RelatedFactory(UserProfileFactory, 'user')

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_username{}'.format(n))
    #print('username=' + username)
    first_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_first_name{}'.format(n))
    last_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_last_name{}'.format(n))
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'test_email{}@example.com'.format(n))
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password', TEST_PASSWORD)

class MainPageTestCase(TestCase):
    """Tests for the main page."""
    def setUp(self_ignored):
        """Insert test users."""
        #print('a User.objects.count()=' + str(User.objects.count()))

        #http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=create#factory.create_batch
        UserFactory.create_batch(TEST_USER_COUNT)

        #print('b User.objects.count()=' + str(User.objects.count()))
```

Continued:

```
    def test_ctrue_is_true(self):
        """Public information should be somewhere on the page."""
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_some_logged_in_users(self):
        """
        In addition to public information, private content for logged in
        users should also be somewhere on the page.
        """
        for  n in range(2):
            self.client.logout()

            test_user = UserFactory()

            print('Attempting to login:')
            profile = test_user.profile
            print('test_user.id=' + str(test_user.id))
            print('   username=' + test_user.username + ', password=' + TEST_PASSWORD)
            print('   first_name=' + test_user.first_name + ', last_name=' + test_user.last_name)
            print('   email=' + test_user.email)
            print('   profile=' + str(profile))
            print('      profile.birth_year=' + str(profile.birth_year))

            did_login_succeed = self.client.login(
                username=test_user.username,
                password=TEST_PASSWORD)
            self.assertTrue(did_login_succeed)

            ##########################################
            # GET PAGE AND TEST ITS CONTENTS HERE...
            ##########################################
```