# How to get "python -m venv" to directly install latest pip version

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

As part of the compilation step for a new python version, I fetch and run [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), to have the latest pip installed next to the python executable:

```
$ /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python --version
Python 3.7.0
$ /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/pip --version
pip 18.0 from /opt/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I have 25 such versions under `/opt/python`, although I mostly use the five latest versions of each major.minor version that is not EOL. To setup an invironment I used to run `virtualenv` or my `virtualenvutils` with the `-p /opt/python/X.Y.Z/bin/python` option to get a virtual environment with a specific version.

With Python 3.7 this gives the imp module deprecation warning:

```
$ virtualenv -p /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python /tmp/py37virtualenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python
Using base prefix '/opt/python/3.7.0'
/opt/util/virtualenvutils/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py:1041: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
New python executable in /tmp/py37virtualenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

I have little hope this will be solved in virtualenv, as this has had a `PendingDeprecationWarning` at least since 2014 (as can be seen from the output in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26550004/1307905))

While investigating replacing `virtualenv` with `python -m venv` in `virtualenvutils`, I first created a new `venv` based virtual environment by hand:

```
$ /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python -m venv /tmp/py37venv
$ /tmp/py37venv/bin/pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /tmp/py37venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

That has an old `pip` version! If you use it, you'll get:

> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command

In the virtual environment created with `virtualenv` you immediately get the latest version:

```
$ /tmp/py37virtualenv/bin/pip --version
pip 18.0 from /tmp/py37virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I can run a post-creation step:

```
/tmp/py37venv/bin/pip install -U --disable-pip-version-check pip
```

which will take extra time. And if there was a some security update for `pip`, this would imply running the non-secure version to get a secure version, an ideal point of attack.

From `virtualenvutils` it is trivial to do the multiple steps to create a `pip`-less virtualenv and then add `pip` using `get-pip.py`. From the command-line this is not so simple:

```
$ /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python -m venv --without-pip /tmp/py37venvnopip
$ /tmp/py37venvnopip/bin/python -c "from  urllib.request import urlopen; response = urlopen('https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip'); open('/tmp/tmp_get_pip.py', 'w').write(response.read())"
$ /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python /tmp/tmp_get_pip.py
......
$ /opt/python/3.7.0/bin/pip --version
```

pip 18.0 from /opt/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

What is causing `/opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python -m venv` to take that old `pip` version? Is that the version available when 3.7.0 was released?

How can I update my install under `/opt/python/3.7.0` in some way so that using `/opt/python/3.7.0/bin/python -m venv` creates a virtualenv with the latest `pip` version without reverting to scripts, aliases or using multiple commands? Having the latest `pip` installed under `/opt/python/3.7.0` obviously is not enough.

There are two bundled wheels:

```
/opt/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ensurepip/_bundled/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
/opt/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I suspect I need to update those. Is there a better way than updating those by hand? Some option for `/some/python -m venv` would be nice.

(And running `/some/python -m ensurepip --upgrade` doesn't do the trick)

---

Running the deprecated `/opt/python/3.7.0/bin/pyvenv` has the same old `pip` version problem.

Comment: It looks like https://bugs.python.org/issue30628 refers to this issue, but the bugs site is currently down.

Comment: To be able to proceed without warnings I ended up creating a [single file utility](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/upgrade_ensurepip/src/default/upgrade_ensurepip.py) that downloads new .whl files in `_bundled` and updates `ensurepip/__init__.py`. Also available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/upgrade-ensurepip/)

Comment: To manually upgrade run
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`
Do not just run `pip install` as it will create a shebang to whatever default pip you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `upgrade-ensurepip` to update those `pip` and `setuptools` wheel files that are part of the `ensurepip` package.  It's not as elegant as being able to upgrade `ensurepip` via `pip`, but it's still preferable to doing it manually.

https://pypi.org/project/upgrade-ensurepip/

Comment: I don't like the idea of user messing with the bundled pip versions (for example, they might be owned by root and installed from OS package manager, you will confuse your OS if you mess with those files)

Comment: Good point.  I have switched to using `conda` and I don't have to deal with this issue now.

Answer (score 18):

The trick is not to *install* the bundled version of pip (which will almost always be out of date), but to *use* it to install the most current version from the internet.

Standard library [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) offers a `--without-pip` flag that can help here. After creating the virtual environment without pip, you can then you can "execute" ensurepip's wheel directly thanks to Python's zip importer.  This is both faster and less hacky than installing pip and then immediately using that same pip installation to uninstall itself and upgrade.

Code speaks louder than words, so here's an example bash function for the process I've described:

```bash
# in ~/.bashrc or wherever

function ve() {
    local py="python3"
    if [ ! -d ./.venv ]; then
        echo "creating venv..."
        if ! $py -m venv .venv --prompt=$(basename $PWD) --without-pip; then
            echo "ERROR: Problem creating venv" >&2
            return 1
        else
            local whl=$($py -c "import pathlib, ensurepip; whl = list(pathlib.Path(ensurepip.__path__[0]).glob('_bundled/pip*.whl'))[0]; print(whl)")
            echo "boostrapping pip using $whl"
            .venv/bin/python $whl/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
            source .venv/bin/activate
        fi
    else
        source .venv/bin/activate
    fi
}
```

If you prefer the older project [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), it also offers `--no-pip`, `--no-setuptools`, and `--no-wheel` flags to achieve the same on Python 2.7.

*Note:* Python 3.9+ `venv` has an `--upgrade-deps` option to immediately upgrade the pip/setuptools versions after creating an environment, see https://bugs.python.org/issue34556 for more info about that. I don't use this option because it still goes through an unnecessary install/uninstall of the vendored versions, which is inferior to the method of creating an environment with the latest versions directly as shown above.

Comment: Funny enough, I have written [a `ve` tool](https://pypi.org/project/ve/) some months ago that does something like that. I might want to polish it, since apparently I am not the only one looking to get around this inconvenience of having to update _pip_ in all virtual environments. Should do it before Python 3.9 comes out though...

Answer (score 3):

It is an expected behavior. `python -m venv` calls `python -m ensurepip` to install `pip` and [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210626/5588279) shows that `ensurepip` would only install the bundled version even with `--upgrade` option. There isn't any official option to update the bundled `pip` and `setuptools`.

Well I have also no good idea to fix this problem as it just is the designed behavior. I would like to give two suggestions:

1. Use `pipenv`. It is really good! And it will be the next-generation official package manager in the future(Although there is a big problem related to current Pypi's structure. In short, a package manager can only decide the dependencies with downloading the whole package. This gives a huge difficulty to building dependencies graph.).
2. Implement your custom `EnvBuilder`, actually there is an [official example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#an-example-of-extending-envbuilder) about this. And in the example, it also use `get-pip.py` to install the latest `pip`.

Comment: Thanks for the envbuilder link, I'll look into that. `pipenv` has quite a bit of overlap with `virtualenvutils`for my use-case, but I would still have to make links to the actual executables in `/usr/local/bin`. The announced use of `Pipfile` by `pipenv` and the horror of yet another config file in every project's root (in the superfluous TOML format to boot) makes it rather uninteresting in the longer term.

Comment: `pipenv` does not just overlap with `virtualenvutils` but is a combination of `pip` and `virtualenv` which means it fully covers these two tools. And further, if you decide to use `pipenv`, you don't need `requirements.txt` any more :-) Actually the biggest reason I choose `pipenv` is that it can really manage dependencies instead of just list them as `pip freeze > requirements.txt` do. For example, you delete one top dependency in `Pipfile` and then run `pipenv clean`, it will automatically delete all unused sub dependencies. Well, after all, it depends on personal opinion :-)

Comment: `virtualenvutils` is not `virtualenv`, it does a bit more than that. As I already got rid of needing a `requirements.txt` (and `setup.cfg`, `Makefile`, `tox.ini`, `setup.py`, `dist`, `build`, `.tox`, etc.) anything `pipenv` puts there only clutters the development tree again. So `pipenv` (*for me*) is just extra work without benefit. Whenever I change dependencies that remove things, I save, then reinstall, a utility and its virtualenv from scratch (there is bound to be a new micro version of the used Python anyway), to get the right dependencies (and restore if that cannot be resolved).

Comment: Guess we have different usage scenarios.

Comment: I think [pipenv should probably not be recommended these days](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4058). Extending `EnvBuilder` looks interesting though.

Comment: The official example does not work anymore, for example the setuptools download link is dead. A simpler alternative is to just run `pip install --upgrade pip` inside `post_setup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [virtualenvwrapper](https://doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) you can put upgrade command in `postmkvirtualenv` script. It is in `~/.virtualenvs` folder by default.

Each time you create a new virtual environment, pip would be upgraded.
I know this is not perfect solution, but it's working.

```
# vim ~/.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv 

pip install --upgrade pip
```