# Python: pip version when creating a new virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Running Python 3.7.1 on a Win10 machine.

When I create a new virtualenv `python -m venv new-virtual-env` the pip version being installed is always 10.0.1 
Even though the pip version on my non-virtualenv python is 18.1

Anyone a suggestion how to solve this without having to manually update pip inside the virtualenv ?

Comment: Why you don't want to update pip inside virtualenv? Or you are just wondering about a more straight-forward way of achieving this?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a more straight-forward way. It is just extra steps I need to take, which I feel I shouldn't. Where does python get the pip package from when I have 18.1 installed, but doesn't use it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "python -m venv" to directly install latest pip version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720909/how-to-get-python-m-venv-to-directly-install-latest-pip-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the problem is that the virtual env copies a bunch of files *directly from the original installation folders*, while `pip` normally writes the packages it downloads under the `site_packages` directory.

As the newly created virtual env uses its own files first, it reverts to the old version until you use the magic `python -m pip install pip` inside the virtualenv.

It looks like a minor defect, but I could not find any straight workaround, except consistently upgrading pip in each and every new virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. No real solution unfortunately. Something I have to keep doing as it seems.