# Why does Python still come with the pip version 9 which I believe is very old compared to the current version 19?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Every time pip is installed, the version is always 9.0.1 and there's this rather annoying DEPRECRATION warning about columns. Why not just ship 19 or some newer version?

[EDIT]

NOTE: My question is not **HOW** to install the latest version.

My question is **WHY** doing `sudo apt install python3-pip` simply doesn't come with pip-19 or some version greater than 9.

Because if I remember correctly, updating the system wide pip causes unwanted side effects. Updating pip should only be done in a virtual environment. Now how will a normal end-user know how to avoid that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "python -m venv" to directly install latest pip version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720909/how-to-get-python-m-venv-to-directly-install-latest-pip-version)

Comment: That is not at all related to my question. I know how to install the latest version. My question was **WHY** it doesn't come with the latest version by default.

Comment: With such wording the question is completely off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because each distribution is versioned. 10 major versions of pip have been released since you version of Python was. Only to follow `pip`, it would have required 10 new minor (or even patch) versions of Python.

Packaging and distributing a new version requires a good deal of work which here was just found non necessary, because the end users:

- are warned that a more recent version is available
- can easily download and install it.

Long story short: the general opinion among core Python developpers seem to have been that following pip version just was not worth it.