# Where does venv take pip from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I run `pip --version` I get pip 20.2.4, but when I create a new venv such as

```
python -m venv venv 
venv\Scripts\activate
pip --version
```

I suddenly get version pip 19.2.3 from the venv. I tried to search all my drives for older pip which might get used for creation of pip inside venv but I only found 20.2.4 versions.

Where does `python -m venv` take source for creating pip file in my venv?

NOTE: I am running on Windows as you can see by the way I active the venv.

Comment: `venv\bin\pip` (i guess; on linux it is `venv/bin/pip`).

Comment: yes, that's where it is now, but I am asking how it got there (from where)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51721906/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56229305/7976758; found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+latest

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you, there is the answer - it is being taken from ensurepip module (lib/ensurepip/_bundled). There is also a suggestion how to update it there.