# Python's default venv environment

Tags: python, pip

Default python's venv contains outdated version of pip and no `wheel` module.
Doing `python -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate` makes environment with pip 20.2.3 when 21.1 it available and globally installed.

How can I configure default pip and modules of venv's env so I don't have to run `pip install --upgrade wheel pip` every time I create new env?

System installed version of python is 3.9.3, pip is 21.1.

Comment: Please check these answers; [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720909/how-to-get-python-m-venv-to-directly-install-latest-pip-version/60217751#60217751) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720909/how-to-get-python-m-venv-to-directly-install-latest-pip-version/60217751#60217751)