Pip version trouble in pycharm
So, I want to start a new project in pycharm and it always starts with an outdated version of pip and I have to do the upgrade. It's not really a problem for a project, but it's getting annoying for every project I start to upgrade the pip version.
I checked the version that I have installed globally on my machine and it's the latest version, so it doesn't make sense to my, why and from where does pycharm get that outdated version, if the virtual environment gets its scripts from my python files that are up to date. Please help me!

you are using a virtual environment in Pycharm for each project, right?

And can you open a terminal not in Pycharm but the terminal of Windows (or whatever you are using), and run this command pip install, and if you are getting anything like this, "[notice] A new release of pip is available:...", then it means the pip you have in your parent/main python is outdated and you have to upgrade that so that your virtual environment(s) can use newer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720909/how-to-get-python-m-venv-to-directly-install-latest-pip-version , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+venv+outdated

method1:
Upgrade pip in the Global Python Environment
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Method2:
Set Up a Custom Virtual Environment 
python -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/template_env
source ~/.virtualenvs/template_env/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
deactivate

Choose Add > Existing Environment and navigate to the custom virtual environment you created (~/.virtualenvs/template_env).
